# Jinja 2 conditional display

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, frontend, jinja2

Hi everyone I'm stucking on jinja and looking for the right way to loop my data on my front, someone can help me with that ?

my json data on mongodb

```json
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "623492fea76c5404b9f57476"
    },
    "name": "pour ou contre ",
    "created_by": "admin",
    "created_at": {
        "$date": {
            "$numberLong": "1647612670472"
        }
    },
    "subject": "politique"
}
```

[json data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qTI8X.png)

I want to loop only room where `subject == value` like that

```
{% if current_user.is_authenticated %}
    {% for room in rooms %}
        {% if room.subject == 'politique' %}
            {{ room.room_name }
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

but jinja displaying all my room elements, I wanna just displaying room where `subject == "politique"`
I didn't find the right way to do that !

can someone help me ?

Comment: You're only showing one object – presumably `rooms` would be a list? Can you show the code that loads `rooms` and passes it to the template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i fixed this just bad call in render template  thx for your help AKX

Answer (score 1):

There are some issues with your template, but I think those are typos. You're not showing how you're actually loading the rooms, and I think the issue is in that part.

The code below works for me. Note that I load the rooms from a string, as you're not showing how you load it.

```py
from jinja2 import Template
import json


json_string = """[
    {
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "623492fea76c5404b9f57476"
        },
        "name": "pour ou contre ",
        "created_by": "admin",
        "created_at": {
            "$date": {
                "$numberLong": "1647612670472"
            }
        },
        "subject": "politique"
    },
    {
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "623492fea76c5404b9f57476"
        },
        "name": "no pour ou contre ",
        "created_by": "admin",
        "created_at": {
            "$date": {
                "$numberLong": "1647612670472"
            }
        },
        "subject": "not_politique"
    }
]"""


rooms = json.loads(json_string)
tm = Template("""{% for room in rooms %}
    {% if room.subject == 'politique' %}
       {{ room.name }}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}""")

output = tm.render(rooms=rooms)
print(output)
```

**output**

```
       pour ou contre
```